# jQuery resizable adding trash

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with resizable :)
When I resize div from the left side, jquery adding top and change height.

Generally I want to drag and resize element and then drop into one or more div's. Some kinde of scheduler.

Here is a [sample](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.0.0-beta/demos/dynamic-add-remove.html)

Here is a [code](http://jsbin.com/weweluyiyu/edit?html,css,js,output) on jsbin. Now this sample work's :) But still is wrong :(

Comment: if you add CSS, javascript and html tags to your post (or directly mark the code snippets), they will be correclty syntax highlighted.

Comment: Perhaps if you made simpler example and worked your way up from a working prototype to a full table you would be able to troubleshoot better.

Comment: Now is new sample :) Pls look and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now is much better :)
I set positon relativ for conteren (events class) and top 10px with !important for event :) [Result](http://jsbin.com/loculunoju/1/edit?html,css,js,output)